# Create kubernetes docker-registry secret from yaml file for each lookup namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to dynamic lookup available namespaces and able to create secrets in the namespaces using below  helm chart.

> templates/secrets.yaml

```
{{ range $index, $namespace := (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" "").items }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregcred
  namespace: {{ $namespace.metadata.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
{{- end}}
```

> values.yaml

```
imageCredentials:
  registry: quay.io
  username: someone
  password: sillyness
  email: someone@host.com
```

> _helpers.tpl

```
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- with .Values.imageCredentials }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\":{\"%s\":{\"username\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"email\":\"%s\",\"auth\":\"%s\"}}}" .registry .username .password .email (printf "%s:%s" .username .password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

When  i run this helm chart, i get below error

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: secrets/templates/_helpers.tpl:2:16: executing "imagePullSecret" at <.Values.imageCredentials>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.imageCredentials

I dont know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference the named template "imagePullSecret" inside the range, the context "." you are providing refers to the body of the loop, which does not have the "Values" attribute.

Try providing the root context instead:

```yaml
{{ range $index, $namespace := (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" "").items }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregcred
  namespace: {{ $namespace.metadata.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" $ }}
---
{{- end}}
```

Comment: This was able to run . but it created the secret for one namespace . Instead of creating the secret for all namespaces .

Comment: You're right, I've just noticed that the "---" separator was missing at the end of the range loop, which is required since we define multiple resources in the same yaml file. I've edited my answer by adding it.

Comment: what is i want to create two secrets with different name ``` regcred``` and ```cred``` secrets?