# Not getting the right value that was specified in the values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Secret value is returning NIL

When i run the command below to check the values in the secret

```
kubectl get secret cred2 -n service-b -o jsonpath='{.data.*}' | base64 -d
```

It returns a Nil value. How do i get the value that was passed on the values.yaml file?

```
{"auths":{"%!s(<nil>)":{"username":"%!s(<nil>)","password":"%!s(<nil>)","email":"%!s(<nil>)","auth":"JSFzKDxuaWw+KTolIXMoPG5pbD4p"}}}%`
```

Sample Code used to generate the secret

```
{{ range $index, $namespace := (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" "").items }}
{{ range $.Values.imageCredentials }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:  
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ $namespace.metadata.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" $ }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

```
values.yaml

imageCredentials:
 - name: cred1
   registry: quay.io
   username: someone
   password: sillyness
   email: someone@host.com
 - name: cred2
   registry: quay.io
   username: someone
   password: sillyness
   email: someone@host.com
```

```
_helpers
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\":{\"%s\":{\"username\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"email\":\"%s\",\"auth\":\"%s\"}}}" .registry .username .password .email (printf "%s:%s" .username .password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: It might help to know what the Helm generated output yaml looks like. It's hard to know what it should be without being more familiar with the `{{ range }}`s and `{{template}}` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of `template` (and the Helm-specific `include`) like function calls that take a single parameter.  Here you're passing that parameter as `$`, a special variable that refers to the top-level object.  You probably want `.`, which within a `range` loop refers to the current item.

```yaml
{{ range $.Values.imageCredentials }}
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
{{/*                                               ^ not `$`  */}}
{{ end }}
```

You might be confusing this case with the similar [Create kubernetes docker-registry secret from yaml file for each lookup namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964282/create-kubernetes-docker-registry-secret-from-yaml-file-for-each-lookup-namespac).  In that question, the template is trying to refer to `.Values.imageCredentials`.  This expression can be decomposed as: within `.` (the template parameter), find the field `Values`, and within that find the field `imageCredentials`.  In that question the template parameter must be the top-level Helm object so that it can dereference `.Values`.  But in your example here, you loop over a list in the top-level template, and need to pass the individual values into the supporting template.

```yaml
{{/* Your question: template accepts a sub-item of the values; pass
    `.` or another derived expression */}}
{{- define "imagePullSecret" -}}
{{ printf ... .registry .email ... }}
{{- end -}}

{{/* Other question: template accepts the top-level Helm object; pass
     `$`, a saved reference to the top-level object, or you can use
     `.` outside a `range` or `with` block that redefines it */}}
{{- define "imagePullSecret" -}}
{{- with .Values.imageCredentials }}...{{- end }}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: Heh, I wish SO had a "David is typing ..." like Slack :-D

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `$` passed into your template causes evaluation to be a different variable context than what you expected; it's the *root* of the variables (that's why in your 2nd `range` you have `$.Values` to escape back out of the 1st `range` context over the Namespaces). When using `template` like that, you'll almost always want the variable context provided to be `.` in order to say "use the variable context I'm sitting in" as the principal of least surprise. For this specific case, you could also create a named variable for that 2nd `range` to use (`{{ range $cred := range $.Values.imageCredentials }}`) in order to make it extra explicit, depending on your team's coding style and familiarity with golang templates

Be aware that you're also missing the `---` to separate those `kind: Secret` documents from one another.

```yaml
{{ range $index, $namespace := (lookup "v1" "Namespace" "" "").items }}
{{ range $.Values.imageCredentials }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:  
  name: {{ .name }}
  namespace: {{ $namespace.metadata.name }}
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

running `helm template .` generates:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cred1
  namespace: alpha
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJxdWF5LmlvIjp7InVzZXJuYW1lIjoic29tZW9uZSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoic2lsbHluZXNzIiwiZW1haWwiOiJzb21lb25lQGhvc3QuY29tIiwiYXV0aCI6ImMyOXRaVzl1WlRwemFXeHNlVzVsYzNNPSJ9fX0=
```

which decodes as

```json
{
  "auths": {
    "quay.io": {
      "username": "someone",
      "password": "sillyness",
      "email": "someone@host.com",
      "auth": "c29tZW9uZTpzaWxseW5lc3M="
    }
  }
}
```

and that interior `auth` key similarly: `someone:sillyness`